# Unexpected token - Webpack 2.2.0 and SCSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack

For some reason my `yarn run dev` command is failing due to the following:

```
SyntaxError: /src/components/home/index.scss:Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | .home {
...
```

I'm using webpack 2.2.0 which is setup like so:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        }, {
            test: /\.(scss)/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                'sass-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: function () {
                            return [
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
    ]
}
```

And all I'm doing in my index.js component is `import s from './styles.scss'`. If I remove the `import` statement and allow the app to boot and then put the `import` statement back in while the app is running and refresh the page then the styles are present... I find this extremely odd and haven't encountered this issue before...

Comment: Shouldn't `sass-loader` come at the end of the loader array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1754) explains the reason why you are getting this error:

> I think I found out why it didn't work on the first place. Though Webpack allows requiring static assets on the client side, babel, which compiles the server code, fails to do so as on the server side Node's require understands only JS files. This means that server side rendering is not possible with the default Webpack and babel.

There are several solutions to solve that issue, more or less complex to put in place.

The easiest one, is to ignore .scss on the server as so:

I added a run-server.js file to the project

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  presets: ['es2015-node5', 'stage-0'],
  plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'] //was needed to support decorators
})

require.extensions['.scss'] = () => {
  return;
}

require.extensions['.css'] = () => {
  return;
}

require('./server')
```

Run that with instead:

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./run-server.js"
```

Added to your project:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015-node5 babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy -D
```

Comment: Copied and pasted your module object into my webpack.config.js file and I'm getting the same error... Weird as F.

Comment: Do you have a simple repo where this can be tested?

Comment: It's not in a repo yet (this is gonna be a boilerplate) here's a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lyqm8dki1j2yfb/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: This has solved that issue so thanks for that but this has a created a new issue which is that I keep getting "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." when reading /src/index.js which is `<Provider...`

Comment: No error on my side, here is my version of the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtqns8bjeqk8dux/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: No idea what was going on there, super weird! Thanks for your help.